# How do I make Chiseled Stone Bricks in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I make Chiseled Stone Bricks?

Is it Possible?

Comment: @Ender - It was a signature (@ Seth - which we don't allow in questions. Feel free to put it in your [profile](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/62550/seth-alex-smith) 'about me' section though)

Answer (score 9):

As of Minecraft 1.8, **yes** it is possible to craft Chiseled Stone Bricks with the following crafting recipe:

[image: 2 stone brick slabs, stacked vertically in the crafting bench]

Answer (score 8):

No, they can not be crafted. Look in jungle temples though, and there are chiseled stone bricks there that you can use to build.

(Look at MCWiki before posting. Most of the information is there on the page.)

Comment: Actually, __if__ you play in the __latest snapshot__, you can craft them.

Answer (score 2):

You can find them in these. You can't craft them so the only other way is to get a mod that allows you to craft them.
[image]

Comment: Yes, these are the jungle temples I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Stone Brick is craftable with 4 Stone blocks, the 3 variants of Stone Brick (Cracked, Mossy, and Chiseled) are not craftable but can be located in Jungle Temples as of 1.3.1.

In addition, there are only 3 Chiseled Stone Bricks in each Jungle Temple making them a rather rare block.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can not craft chiseled stone bricks.
Neither can you craft mossy or cracked stone bricks. You may find all of these in jungle temples (updated in 1.3.1), but jungle temples aren't the easiest to find... best to either stick with the normal stone bricks, or get a mod or plugin that allows you to craft these differing stone bricks.

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft 1.8 they are making it so that  you can craft chisled stone bricks. You just put 2 stone brick slabs together on top of each other. Hope i helped! :D

Comment: @ TheCrazyCaptin Do you have a source for this? How did you find out this information?

Answer (score 0):

How you craft them is you need two stone slabs.  I am not sure if you can do this in **1.7.** but im pretty sure you can do this in **1.8**

I hope i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't craft them but you can find them in Jungle Temples or if you are on the PC Version you can switch cheats on and type in /gamemode 1 which is basically saying you want to change your mode to creative and you can have an unlimited supply of it.

Answer (score -2):

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chiseled_Stone_Bricks

Seems to be true, though as of 05/06/14 doesn't currently work. (in 1.7.9)

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  Please summarize the link's information here.  Saves people a click, and ensures your answer is still good, if ever the goes down.